# htaccess redirect between subdomains depending on the file extension

Tags: .htaccess

### Situtation

I have 2 subdomains `www.example.com` and `static.example.com` and they both read the files on the same folder. So:

1. If I go to `https://static.example.com/privacy` I see the same that I see on `https://www.example.com/privacy`
2. If I go to `https://www.example.com/src/file.js` I see the same that I see on `https://static.example.com/src/file.js`
3. Also, both subdomains read the same `.htaccess` file.

### What I want to do

I want is to redirect any request of an image, video, js or css file from `www` to `static` and any other file type from `static` to `www`.

### Expected Behavior

That way, if I go to `https://static.example.com/privacy` I should be redirected to `https://www.example.com/privacy`

And, if I go to `https://www.example.com/src/file.js` I see the same the is on `https://static.example.com/src/file.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
# Identify static resources - set an environment variable
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(?i)\.(jpg|png|gif|mpg|mp4|wmv|js|css)$" STATIC_RESOURCE

# Redirect static resources to static subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{ENV:STATIC_RESOURCE} =1
RewriteRule \.([\w]{2,4})$ https://static.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect "other" requests to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.
RewriteCond %{ENV:STATIC_RESOURCE} ^$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Although, I assume your site is already linking to the appropriate subdomain?

You could just force a 404 instead?

Comment: Updated answer - Corrected substitution string on the second `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Yes, the site links to the right subdomains, is just to avoid duplications. Now... for some reason, this code is only redirecting on the index.

Comment: Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? These redirects will need to go near the top, _before_ any existing rewrites (and/or front-controller).

Comment: Is on the very top. The statics files redirects to the index of the www domain

Comment: "statics files redirects to the index of the www domain" - That would seem to be completely the opposite?

Comment: You've "accepted" the answer - do I assume it's now working as intended?